# If $a_n$ converges absolutely, then is it true that $\sum |a_n|^r$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the fact that the series $a_n$ converges absolutely implies the fact that $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|a_n|^r<+\infty$$ for $0<r<2$?

For $r>1$ we have:

From the fact that $a_n$ converges absolutely we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|=0$, it means that there exist $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ we have $|a_n|<1$. Then, since for all $n>n_0$ we have $|a_n|^r<|a_n|$ and $\sum_{n=n_0+1}^{+\infty}|a_n|<+\infty$ we conclude that $\sum_{n=n_0+1}^{+\infty}|a_n|^r<+\infty$ and consequently $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|a_n|^r<+\infty$.

Comment: For $r\ge1$ yes, for $r<1$ no.

Comment: Thank you. Could you recommend me a way to prove that?

Comment: For a counterexample, take $a_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ and $r=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: For $r\ge 1$, use the comparison-test.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question. I would be very grateful for the information on whether the proof is correct.